# Why does sphinx format my docstring parameters on the same line

Tags: python-3.x, python-sphinx

I am relatively new to sphinx and wanted to generate documentation for a project of mine. An example of one of my functions is found within predict.py:

```
def arima_rolling_forecast(training_set, testing_set, order, solver='lbfgs'):
    """
    Runs an ARIMA rolling forecast with a given training and testing set.
    :param pandas.Series training_set: training set.
    :param pandas.Series testing_set: testing set.
    :param collections.namedtuple order: ARIMA order (p, d, q).
    :param string solver: the solver used for the rolling average. Defaults to lbfgs.
    :return: the forecast of predicted values.
    :rtype: list
    """
    previous_results = list(training_set)
    predictions = []
    for result in testing_set:
        tmp_model = ARIMA(previous_results, order=order)
        tmp_model_fit = tmp_model.fit(disp=False, solver=solver)
        forecast, _, _ = tmp_model_fit.forecast()
        predictions.append(forecast[0])
        previous_results.append(result)
    return predictions
```

When I use the `make html` command, the documentation is almost correct, however the return type and params are appended to function description as seen below: 
[image]

How do I change this so that the `param` `return` and `rtype` are put onto separate lines? Or is this how the documentation is meant to look?

Answer (score 6):

You need to add a blank line between the description and the first `:param blah blah:`.  See syntax for [Info field lists](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/domains.html#info-field-lists).

I'm unsure whether pandas data types are supported.  You'll need to do your own research to make that determination.

Comment: Adding a line didn't do anything... But then again completely delete all the comments also appeared to do nothing. Probably an error on my end. Cheers for the link :)

Comment: "delete all the comments"? What comments?

Comment: 1. soo old...   2. he meant 'docstring'.... 3. worked for me.... 4. OP probably didn't `make html` to re-render.

Comment: Adding a blank line between arguments worked for me. I am on Sphinx 6.2.1 using Google docstring and readthedocs theme.