# Sphinx doesn't parse rst docstrings correctly

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

So I've been trying to make some documentation for my project. I found Sphinx, and it looked great, so I chose that. Now, I'm trying to use its autodoc function, however, it doesn't work properly. At first, I thought that it was because my docstrings are not of the rst style, however, they are.

This is, for example, a docstring for the parse_data function:

```
    """
    Parse the data as GET parameters and return it.
    :param data: A dictionary containing values for the api call.
    :type data dict
    :return: A proper GET param string
    :rtype str
    """
```

And this is my .rst file:

```
API
===

.. autoclass:: launchlibrary.Api
   :members:

   .. automethod:: __init__
```

`launchlibrary.Api` contains parse_data, of course.

My result looks like this:

[image]

I expected the autodoc to look closer to what is available on the python-twitter API documentation, for example:

[image]

Does anyone have any idea what might be happening? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add a blank line before the `:param:` line.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/49564783/407651 (even though the OP of that question said that adding a line did not help).

Comment: worked here, should post it as the answer