# How to make Sphinx recognize the `:param` element?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

I want to use Sphinx to generate html documents, and although I can generate them successfully, Sphinx does not recognize elements like `:param content:`.

#### Wrong document

[image: Figure 1: Wrong document]

#### Correct document

[image: Figure 2: Correct document]

Here you can see the specific code file, using `. \make.bat html` to generate the documentation: [Shared/sphinx-document-generation at master - Andy-AO/Shared](https://github.com/Andy-AO/Shared/tree/master/sphinx-document-generation)

After checking the documentation of the `autodoc` extension, I still can't find the relevant settings, maybe I'm missing something important.

Why is this happening? How can I get Sphinx to recognize these elements?

Comment: Please provide the source of the document.

Comment: @KlausD.[Shared/sphinx-document-generation at master · Andy-AO/Shared](https://github.com/Andy-AO/Shared/tree/master/sphinx-document-generation)

Comment: Add a blank line after "describe".

Comment: Looks like duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/49564783/407651

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank @mzjn, the problem has been solved, it is the format of reStructuredText is wrong.

1. There should be a blank line between other content and Field lists

   ×

   ```
           """
           describe
               :param child_node: this is child_node
   ```

   √

   ```
           """
           describe

           :param child_node: this is child_node
   ```
2. There should be spaces between the Field and the content of the Field

   - × - `:param content:the object to be added`
   - √ - `:param content: the object to be added`